# What happened to Doug Engelbart's NLS?

Tags: history, gui, pdp-10, timesharing

Apparently, it was sold to "Tymshare" in 1977, but what happened to it after that? Who has the software now? Could it ever be emulated?

Comment: The place to start seems to be the [Doug Engelbart Institute](https://dougengelbart.org/). It may also be worth asking the Computer History Museum what because of their attempt to [restore the NLS software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLS_(computer_system)#Decline_and_succession).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it was sold to Tymshare.  The project continued under the name Augment, running on a modified TENEX, called August, on a KA10 computer.  It was later ported to TOPS-20 on a KL10.  Tymshare also made an "Augment Engine" based on a Foonly PDP-10 compatible computer.  I *believe* it was last running on the KLH10 emulator.  There was a project to revive this - https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/nlsproject/ and http://chm.cim3.net/wiki/NLS_Restoration.html - but it is rumored to have stalled due to unresolved IP rights.